# Bash slash does't work in wildcards square brackets

Tags: bash, wildcards

I'm curious why command `ls -pd *[!/]` or `ls -pd *[!\/]` doesn't match all files which don't end with `/`.

My use case is that I want to list only files inside the current working directory. I know that it's better to use `find` instead of `ls` but I want to understand in general is it possible to use `/` in square brackets in wildcards.

Comment: You might get more traction on this question on stackoverflow

Comment: In the manual, [Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) says "When matching a filename, the slash character must always be matched explicitly by a slash in the pattern". Other than that, I can't find anything that says `*/` only expands to directories. Note that the slash is not actually part of the filename. Having said all that, I don't know how to formulate a glob pattern that excludes directories.

Comment: perhaps `ls -pd1 * | grep -v '/$'`

Comment: @glennjackman thanks for the answer. But it's strange that's it's not documented in the manual or other sources. I can match other special characters with quoting them in square brackets. But back slash doesn't work.

Comment: @AlexMisiulia The slash isn't actually part of the filename, it's a delimiter *after* the filename, so it's inherently going to act differently from characters that're part of the filename.

Comment: @GordonDavisson thanks. Maybe you have some reference to documentation which can describe deeply this topic?